# Scala using enum to string in match case

Tags: scala, enums, match

what I want to achieve in here is to compare a `string` with a value of an `enum`
first, I tried it using if

```
object FooType extends Enumeration {
  type FooType = Value
  val FooA = Value("FA")
  val FooB = Value("FB")
}

val x = "FA"
if (x == FooType.FooA)  //Does not match
  println("success using if without toString")
if (x == FooType.FooA.toString) //match
  println("success using if with toString")

println(FooType.FooA) //will print into "FA"
```

at least, it still working well when I compare it to the `enum` with `toString` method. but if I change it to a `match case`, it would turn into an `error` instead

```
x match {
  case FooType.FooA.toString => println("success using match")
}

ScalaFiddle.scala:19: error: stable identifier required, but ScalaFiddle.this.FooType.FooA.toString found.
    case FooType.FooA.toString => println("success using match")
                      ^
```

is there any way to achieve this by using match case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to convert the `String` into `FooType` and then use match

```scala
  object FooType extends Enumeration {
    type FooType = Value
    val FooA = Value("FA")
    val FooB = Value("FB")
  }

  val x = FooType.withName("FA")

  x match {
    case FooType.FooA => println("matched")
    case _            => println("did not match")
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are converting a type in your match case, that is not allowed, you can do something like this:

```
object FooType extends Enumeration {
  type FooType = Value
  val FooA = Value("FA")
  val FooB = Value("FB")
}

val x = "FA"

x match {
    case str if str == FooType.FooA.toString => println("success using match")
    case _            => println("did not match")
  }
```

or you can do something similar to what @Ivan Stanislavciuc suggested

```
x match {
    case str if FooType.withName(str) == FooType.FooA => println("success using match")
    case _            => println("did not match")
  }
```